# Looping a function over multiple files

Tags: r

I wrote a simple function:

```
myfunction <- function(fileName, stringsAsFactors=TRUE,                 
                   check.names=FALSE,               
                   skip =1,...) {
Data <- read.delim(fileName, skip = skip,                     
                 stringsAsFactors=stringsAsFactors,                      
                 check.names = check.names, ...)                   
cb    <- list()                       
Index <- as.numeric(as.factor(Data[,1]))              
cb    <-  cbind(Data, Index)              
return(cb)
}
```

This function takes the first column of the file named Data, create an Index according to that first column and then cbind the file Data and the index created.

This function will be applied in file named: `myfile_00.txt`, `myfile_01.txt` and so on. For one single file it looks like:

```
myfunction (fileName = "myfile_00.txt")
myfunction (fileName = "myfile_01.txt")
.......
```

I have around 1000 files so I suppose, the loop can be as from another post:

```
mytxt  <- dir(pattern=".txt")      
n      <- length(mytxt)      
mylist <- vector("list", n)   
for(i in 1:n) {
    mylist[[i]] <- read.delim(mytxt[i], header = F, skip = 1)
}
```

then:

```
d <- lapply(mylist, myfunction)
```

Unfortunately it does not work... When using `lapply` an error occurs:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
'file' must be a character string or connection
```

Since I' m new in R probably I' m doing mistakes I'm not able to figure out.

Comment: why are you reading in twice? You use `read.delim` in your function as well..? and your for-loop reads using `read.delim` as well.

Comment: okk, thank you for this first suggestion. So it is sufficient to write: myfunction<- function(myfile[[i]]){
Index <- as.numeric(as.factor(myfile[[i]][,1]))
cb = cbind(myfile[[i]], Index)
return(cb)
}

Comment: It is better the way @flodel has shown. Pass the files as input argument to the function and do the loading of file inside the function. Check flodel's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @Arun pointed out, you are trying to run your function twice: once on the files and once one the data frames you have created... Instead, your code should look like this:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".txt")
mylist <- lapply(files, myfunction)
```