# How to analyse many excel files with R

Tags: r

I've got a folder with more than 1000 excel files in csv and now I want to analyse them with R. 
I already created some statistic commands and tested them in one excel file (all excel files have the same table structure, only the filenames and the data in the tables is different).

Is there a easy way to load all of the excel files in R to run my tests over all sheets?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Maverick You can read it in a `list` and do all the operations within the list, then save it back.  Is there any pattern for the `filenames` and also are these in the same working folder?

Comment: This question has been posed and answered many a time on SO. You can start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937151/looping-a-function-over-multiple-files

Comment: It's a bit misleading to call CSV "Excel-Files". It's somewhat unexpected that Excel reads these text files predating Excel.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are all `.csv`, this could be read with `read.csv` in a `list`.  Assuming that the files are in the working directory,

```
files <- list.files(pattern='yourpattern.csv')

lst <- lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x,header=TRUE))
lapply(lst, yourfunction)
```